# Views show content where field used in user and node entity matches

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have an entity reference field called 'field_client' (client) used on both the user entity and on a node content type called 'ticket'.

I'd like to build a view that only shows nodes where this entity reference field value matches the logged in user's client entity reference field value.

I'm struggling to determine how to build the contextual filter and if a relationship is required.